# Explicit HTML is incorrectly parsed by JSoup

Tags: macros, jsoup, confluence

I'm using JSoup for parsing HTML. It generally works OK, but in some explicit example it changes element sequence in HTML after parsing. Here is the simple code:

```
String str1 = originalHtmlFragment;
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(str1);
String str2 = doc.html();
```

Here are the values of str1 and str2.

str1:

```
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p>10</p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">
                        <p>
                            <ac:macro ac:name="my-macro">
                                <ac:parameter ac:name="outer-values">Page content</ac:parameter>
                                <ac:parameter ac:name="atlassian-macro-output-type">INLINE</ac:parameter>
                                <ac:rich-text-body>
                                    <p>a1</p>
                                </ac:rich-text-body>
                            </ac:macro>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

str2:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>10</p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">
                        <p>
                            <ac:macro ac:name="my-macro">
                                <ac:parameter ac:name="outer-values">Page content</ac:parameter>
                                <ac:parameter ac:name="atlassian-macro-output-type">INLINE</ac:parameter>
                                <ac:rich-text-body></ac:rich-text-body>
                            </ac:macro>
                        </p>
                        <p>a1</p>
                        <p>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that a1 is outside ac:macro tag in the second code example.
How can I work around that in JSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to parse a String that is not real HTML, since `ac:macro` is not an allowed tag name. JSoup tries to do something sensible but in your case it obviously fails in this attempt. If you can switch to the XMLparser implementation, you get the results as expected:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str1,"",Parser.xmlParser());
```

Comment: @AlexeyCe if you feel that the answer helped you, please consider accepting it. This will mark this question as answered. see here for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi! Yes, i tried to vote but I don't have enough points. I checked 'v' sign, as it is allowed for me. Thanks! :)